# Need help creating rocks to spawn on random location

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, game-physics

I'm making a Bullet Hell Shooter game on a basic standard level, I'm using AS3 and don't want to use any packages. I'm a game design student and my skills are really low. I been trying to look for falling rocks to spawn from different places, but all I get is like 10 rocks all in one rock and they don't re spawn after it goes off the screen.

MY current code is:

```
    var background = new Background;

background.x = 200;
background.y = 200;

addChild(background);

var ship = new Ship

ship.x = 125;
ship.y = 350;

addChild(ship);



var rock = new Rock

var result:Number = Math.random() * 100 
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth
rock.x = randomX;

addChild(rock);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler_2);

function fl_EnterFrameHandler_2(event:Event):void
{
    rock.y +=5;
}






ship.gotoAndStop("normal");


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,fl_KeyboardDownHandler);

function fl_KeyboardDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void

{

        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)

        {

        ship.x +=5;

        }
          if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)

        {

        ship.x -=5;

        }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,detectCollision);
function detectCollision(event:Event)
{
         if(ship.hitTestObject(rock))
     {
         ship.gotoAndPlay("boom");
         ship.stop();
         stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,fl_KeyboardDownHandler);

     }
}
```

Comment: Firstly In this code you spawn only one rock and secondly - where is the code that check when rock leave the stage ( i.e. someting like stageHeight < rock.y )

Comment: Your current code create only one rock not 10.

Comment: @AzzyElvul 

My current code is: [link](http://i.imgur.com/Loescuz.jpg?1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
var rocks = new Array();
// Create 10 rocks
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
   var rock = new Rock();
   rock.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
   rock.y = 0;
   rocks.push( rock );
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,stepDown);
function stepDown(event:Event)
{
   // step down each rock
   for ( var i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      rocks[i].y += 5;
       // Check if rocks fall from stage than set it on new position
      if ( stage.stageHeight < rocks[i].y )
      {
         rocks[i].y = 0;
         rocks[i].x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth
      }
   }
}
```

Here can be severel mistakes, but you can understand the way

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the code, the rocks are finally spawning continuously at random spots. I've been stuck here literally for a month, I'm really grateful for this! 

thank you